# TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational when using sympy piecewise

Tags: python, piecewise, uniform-distribution

In my researches, I couldn't find any examples related to a relational value in piecewise functions. Although I received the *lower* and *upper* values with the *uni_dis* method, i'm stuck in the process of transferring these values to the piecewise function. What's the reason?

```
from sympy import Symbol, Piecewise
import sympy as sym
import sympy.plotting as syp
import math

a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
x = Symbol('x')
function = 1 / abs(a-b)

def uni_dis(lower, upper):
    if lower > upper:
        lower, upper = upper, lower
    uniform = Piecewise((0, x < lower), (0, x > upper), (function.subs({a:lower, b:upper}), x >= lower and x <= upper))
    syp.plot(uniform.subs((x,-10,10), title="uni_dis"))

uni_dis(231, 675)
```

My error message is as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c28135b22fc4> in <module>
----> 1 uni_dis(231, 675)

<ipython-input-2-e4a205990c2a> in uni_dis(lower, upper)
      2     if lower > upper:
      3         lower, upper = upper, lower
----> 4     uniform = Piecewise((0, x < lower), (0, x > upper), (function.subs({a:lower, b:upper}), x >= lower and x <= upper))
      5     syp.plot(uniform.subs((x,-10,10), title="uni_dis"))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    374 
    375     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 376         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    377 
    378     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify `x >= lower and x <= upper` to `(x >= lower) & (x <= upper)`.
The problem is that logical evaluations with SymPy objects can return an another symbolic logic that cannot be deduced to True or False.
You can see how `(x >= lower).__class__` returns an another sympy inequality instance.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting logical expressions, I got an " *TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable* " error. After doing some research, I learned that the plot method can be used with the piecewise method as [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/8577#issuecomment-113537158). And that's it.

Corrected version of the code:

```
def uniform_dist(lower, upper):
    if lower > upper:
        lower, upper = upper, lower
    syp.plot(Piecewise((0, x < lower), (0, x > upper), (f.subs({a:lower, b:upper}), (x >= lower) & (x <= upper))), (x,-10,10), title="uniform distribution")
```